# Is there a way to map a function return depending on the value of a object parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have an type that omits one key of an interface. I want to declare a function signature where Typescript can infer the return is the type or the interface:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
    d: string;
}

type SomeTypeFromInterface = Omit<SomeInterface, 'd'>;

let test: SomeTypeFromInterface;

interface Config{
    withD: boolean;
    some: string;
    other: string;
    values: string;
}

function getObject(config: Config): SomeInterface | SomeTypeFromInterface  {

    if (config.withD) {
        return {} as unknown as SomeInterface;
    } else {
        return {} as unknown as SomeTypeFromInterface;
    }
}

const myConfig: Config = {
    withD: true,
    some: 'some',
    other: 'other',
    values: 'values',
}

const myObject = getObject(myConfig);
myObject.d // <-- should exist
```

currently [typescript doesn't infer correctly the return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=36&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2ECS5rxLIDeAUMhcnAFzIgCumARtANzmVO0DOYUoAc3aVkCWk3ToANhDghhlACY8%20g9gF9SpMAE8ADigzYAKvogAxKFjyRYiFAF5kAeUzAwAHiO58dpABpkAHJFIIA%20dlIZMGRIXlpvUwNLa19CCEjQW3TkAGF0EBhgATIRAHd3AAsAEXFJGTkFCm4sCBV%20ECEOCnQwSuh2tW7kADc4KXoIbkHOjS0YehAEMGAC5AEIMGcmACsIZYAKBAKigVp8wuKASgTWmwJ7ZAAfNFakiytMe78UEi0RYAwZBHE7FAB0FT61SufxEIigm3oUBAJHUVG4yEWAGsQOgyii4BjvN90k1kGiIFJuChSnCKAiwEiUcQ0YTMSAcXiCUS3mYUl80vYyZpNKRjiBeMhMDoLqdzqCBMgnLSKJCarQ%20JN-MMWthaEFdRAgtqRL1%20lB9WboMbhmMJlN9XbJtwbaLxZLpds9ssletNl79mADtLZdd2EA):

[image: typescript doesn't infercorrectly the return type]

Is this possible?

I tried to do this:

```
type Function1 = (t1: Config) => { [D in keyof Config]: null extends Config[D] ? SomeTypeFromInterface : SomeInterface };

const  getObject: Function1 = (config: Config)=> {

    if (config.withD) {
        return {} as unknown as SomeInterface;
    } else {
        return {} as unknown as SomeTypeFromInterface;
    }
}
```

but it does not work.

Edit:

[Link to code related to my comment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-mILCUFGM5mafjc8R85XkMXS+WC2rzKGtYGnO0qO93hQXQJkJh9FyeZyPa7kK5m8hk-RBHMghNOth6KEDxBQnv00MRlAj5foGeJtNZvMj4+5nx7+R3oiAFSokqz+clzTCF6ieHda24E9Fn6C9hlGTENCWB8ZjfaDtGQb9ERWad-3iedfVdJVfgVNdgJqUDoRmOFz0grojxPD9uFva8wmYxjqFfZ8wk499zyncgZzw-QAHVbD6HlSI3Ldnl3fc6LCBiaOoZibzgqB2KoHiXxQ+YP34wS530R1ZS5UipWMll50XP0xHnCywC5BMVGQA1vAAWjcgFgAEPgVgMuyZTJH4zIdQK5Xw4jXV5WyjLCn4nPYFyUXczzoFsKAQhUdB5gYIYvJ8vzcMM+zRJKCpXHMsLmXnUrxJspKfTy9EywAQkKkBZ0UZj7JC6UnTlYhNwo5AYWo5AVOQAAiSaQigqaZqmHSFnm5AtGi-UUQMrq1Ps+gAAVgAQItfEFGsQkmuBJuQb1JpYK6boQSbIgobar3shKGrS9AMoHY5jDJCAVHa2dhmAKAVB6irQv65lBukgBZXE6gTKBFCyzBmVTbxkAABgTABWEIJum2b5JJxan2W6bVvW8gDQM0Hwd2wd-HyTZvQOo6TuwUdgimy7rqmu7Bcmx7nvIRmIbCj6DQEYBZAxL6fqxUkUC8OdyjqeJS3iNgEiveFyCAA) in [@jcalz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272380/is-there-a-way-to-map-a-function-return-depending-on-the-value-of-a-object-param#comment102934205_58273128)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few places where you need to guide the compiler through keeping track of whether `withD` is `true` or `false` (as opposed to just `boolean`) and how `getObject()`'s return value is dependent on that.

---

First, you need the type of `myConfig` to depend on whether its `withD` property is `true` or `false`; you can't annotate its type as `Config`, since that is wide enough to represent either case.  The compiler will immediately forget that `const myConfig: Config = {...}` had `withD` as `true`.  The easiest way to do this is just not to use a type annotation at all.  You don't need to *say* that `myConfig` conforms to `Config`.  TypeScript has a [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) type system; if `myConfig` conforms to `Config`, you will still be able to pass it to a function requiring a `Config`.

So first we do that:

```
const myConfig = {
    withD: true,
    some: 'some',
    other: 'other',
    values: 'values',
}
```

Let's check the type of `myConfig`:

```
/* const myConfig: {
    withD: boolean; // whoops
    some: string;
    other: string;
    values: string;
} */
```

Uh oh, `withD` is still inferred as just `boolean`.  That leads us to the next place we need to intervene:

---

You want `true` and `false` to be distinguished at the type level, meaning that `true` and `false` should be treated as [`boolean` *literal* types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9407) themselves.  Note that in TypeScript, the `boolean` type is equivalent to the union type `true | false`.

When you write a value like `{ withD: true }`, the compiler will first interpret the property as the `true` literal type, but will then generally [widen the type to `boolean` unless you tell it not to](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).

There are various ways to tell it not to.  Since TypeScript 3.4, one of the easiest is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).  If you add `as const` to a literal value, it will tend to be inferred to be as narrow as possible.  So, let's try this:

```
const myConfig = {
    withD: true as const,
    some: 'some',
    other: 'other',
    values: 'values',
}
```

which results in

```
/* const myConfig: {
    withD: true;
    some: string;
    other: string;
    values: string;
} */
```

Great.  Note that you could have put `as const` other places (such as `const myConfig = {...} as const`), or done something else like `{withD: true as true}`, but this is sufficient.

---

Now `myConfig` is known to have a `true` value for `withD`, so we have to modify `getObject()` to care about that.  One possible way to do this is with [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).  (I'll just give the overload solution; you can also use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types), but overloads are maybe easier to understand)

```
interface YesConfig extends Config {
    withD: true
}
interface NoConfig extends Config {
    withD: false
}

// call signatures
function getObject(config: YesConfig): SomeInterface;
function getObject(config: NoConfig): SomeTypeFromInterface;
function getObject(config: Config): SomeInterface | SomeTypeFromInterface;
// implementation
function getObject(config: Config): SomeInterface | SomeTypeFromInterface {
    if (config.withD) {
        return {} as unknown as SomeInterface;
    } else {
        return {} as unknown as SomeTypeFromInterface;
    }
}
```

Here for convenience I've added `YesConfig` and `NoConfig` types to represent the difference in `withD`, and then there are three call signatures.  If `config` is `YesConfig`, then the output is `SomeInterface`.  If `config` is `NoConfig`, then the output is `SomeTypeFromInterface`.  If `config` is just `Config` (so if the compiler can't tell), then the output is the union of both types.  And the implementation signature must be able to handle all of the call signatures, which it can.

Now, finally, you can do this:

```
const myObject = getObject(myConfig);
myObject.d // <-- no error!
```

And it works!  The compiler selects the first call signature, and the output type is `SomeInterface`.

---

For completeness, let's see some other ways of using this:

```
const anotherObject = getObject({ withD: false, other: "", some: "", values: "" });
// const anotherObject: Pick<SomeInterface, "a" | "b" | "c">
anotherObject.d; // error, as expected
```

Here, `anotherObject` has `withD` of `false` and the output is `SomeTypeFromInterface`; so we've used the second call signature above.  Note that we didn't have to use `as const`, because the object literal was immediately passed to `getObject()`. The compiler knows that some of the `getObject()` call signatures care about literal types for the `withD` property, so it does not widen the `false` to `boolean`.  We only had to do that before because you put your config into a separate variable before using it, by which time it was too late not to widen the type.

And finally,

```
const thirdObject = getObject({ withD: Math.random() < 0.5, other: "", some: "", values: "" });
// const thirdObject: SomeInterface | Pick<SomeInterface, "a" | "b" | "c">
thirdObject.d; // still error, since it might not be there
```

Here we truly have no idea whether `withD` will be `true` or `false`, and so the compiler selects the third call signature, where the output is a union.

---

Whew!  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=63&ssc=59&pln=57&pc=1#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-0gQPB0MR6Oxsv63bCFNoNOqogAHyH1bStjrI8b8NtwEwhnk2HALtbTZzrfbBa7xZ7mL7GMHfnrBXHKRr07PvNlVGAMGQJf7ADoTUmjdxuO7XVA28RWTga5vQAaxAdBqjbICJ38fInCJZBWQgc0UDvL8fzdf9AOAkAwIgqDrkvKcMjgzMJlhWEVluDYtk7It9h3OjozRUsBzEWjC19F8VGQG1kG8ABaATtRFYABD4KiURocDhmgJj4lcfN5KjYhkBNegzQtEIKXoAAiXSQhJZB9JCekFmM3TEKTMQ+Oo+JFApeT6AABWABAQN8YdSIgEJdLgSzx10lgAuMhBdMiCgHNkqB5O49heNtaBbCgEJoNFYxfQgFRJLueJhmAKAVHkhilM44tVPU5AAFkXTqF8oEUFQsCjD9vGQAAGF8AFZtOivSDKpLp+tMmZIX6qybNtOyEjqAqirKqtYIzFBx1c9zPOwG9gmM-zkEC4K9tC8K9FmwrYpUeK+IEYBZAdJL0BSx0fRQLxNnKOp4hkngUGiy0gA)

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful explanation! I have seen I can also keep the `Config` interface private and just use `YesConfig` and `NoConfig` as types in the function implementation. It allows me and force me to define the type of the config object I want to send and throws and error if it is not defined. I have added the link this this in my answer because it is too long to paste here.